# By elisp how to change backgound color when specific theme is activated?

Tags: frames, themes

How do we set "white" background when only "adwaita" theme is activated.
The following does not work.

```
(when (equal 'custom-enabled-themes "adwaita")
  (set-background-color "white"))
```

Comment: `C-h f set-background-color` tells you that it just sets the background color of the selected frame. And `C-h v custom-enabled-themes` tells you that it's a *list* of themes, (and those are symbols, not strings).

Comment: Why don't you create a new theme, inherit from "adwaita" and specify the background you want?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the `adwaita` theme, but altered so that the background is white. The usual way to do this would be to create a customized them and load that.

To do this, start with `M-x customize-create-theme`, which opens up a buffer with options for making new themes. Then click on the `visit theme` button, and enter `adwaita`. This opens up the settings for `adwaita`.

Scroll down to the `default` face, click on the arrow, and change `background` to the colour you want. You can use the colour picker, or just enter `#ffffff` for white.

You can save this them by clicking the `Save Theme` button at the top of the file. This will save a modified version of `adwaita` that will be used the next time you load this theme.

If you want to keep the old version of `adwaita`, change the name in the `Theme name` box at the top of the file before you save it. For instance, you could call your theme `adwaita-white`. Then you can load the modified them with that name, or the original theme using `adwaita`.

For more details see the Emacs manual:

[Custom Themes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Custom-Themes.html)

[Creating Custom Themes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Creating-Custom-Themes.html)

[Custom Themes (elisp)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Custom-Themes.html#Custom-Themes)